# Sum All Inputs With Same Class On Change - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have inputs with `class="amount"`.  The # of inputs is dynamically controlled by the user - but I doubt that is important. I then have an input with `id="total"`

```
<form>
  <input class="amount">
  <input class="amount">
  <input class="amount">

  <input id="total">
</form>
```

I would like to sum the values in the inputs with `.amount` and place that sum with `#total`.  I would like for this calculation to occur as changes happen in any of the ".amount" inputs.  I am quite new to the use of JS and I am struggling with the cleanest way to approach solving this use case.

Thanks!

Comment: Hook to the `input` event on the `.amount` elements, then loop through them all and add the values. If you're stuck with a specific part, please add your code to the question. SO is here to help you debug code, not to write it for you.

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATED ANSWER :** You can check by running the snippet here.

```js
$('.amount').on("input", function() {
  let total = 0;
  $('.amount').each(function() {
    total += $(this).val()/1;
  })
  $('#total').val(total);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input class="amount" placeholder="One"><br/>
  <input class="amount" placeholder="Two"><br/>
  <input class="amount" placeholder="Three"><br/>
  <input id="total" placeholder="Total" readonly>
</form>
```

Comment: Hi Pranav that is quite similar to what I was trying only I had ```var``` instead of ```let``` I am returning "NaN" in the  total input.  When I try to replace it with your code above it just consistently returns 0 as the total regardless of what value I put in.

Comment: @GXM100 I have updated the code. It will definitely work now. You can check it by running it here as well.

Comment: This code works well from my side.
I used parseFloat and it returns NaN. 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<form id="form_input">
  <input class="amount">
  <input class="amount">
  <input class="amount">

  <input id="total">
</form>
```

**Use following Step in j query**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$('#form_input').on("keyup", ".amount", function () {

    var sum = 0;

    $('.amount').each(function () {
        sum += Number($(this).val());
    });

    $('#total').val(sum);

});
```

});

**Then use this code in your delete row function**

```
$(wrapper).on("click", ".remove_field", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
        i--;

        var sum = 0;

            $('.item_price').each(function () {
                sum += Number($(this).val());
            });

            $('#Item_total_price').html(sum);
            console.log(sum);
    });
```

**Reference**

[Java script calculation dynamic add row value](https://github.com/islamyearul/laravel-help-line/blob/master/Java%20script%20calculation%20dynamic%20%20add%20row%20value)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a pure Javascript solution using [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) on the list of `.amount` elements.

```js
const summands = document.querySelectorAll(".amount");
const total = document.querySelector("#total");

summands.forEach(x =>

  addEventListener("input", (e) => {

    total.value =
      Array.from(summands)
      .map((x) => x.value)
      .reduce((a, c) => Number(a) + Number(c));

  }));
```

```html
<form>
  <input class="amount" placeholder="input value"><br/>
  <input class="amount" placeholder="input value"><br/>
  <input class="amount" placeholder="input value"><br/>
  <input id="total" placeholder="Total" readonly>
</form>
```